# Generating ChartJs graph dynamically - odd behavior in mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, chart.js

So here I am trying to create a graph with ChartJS http://jsfiddle.net/1sc6L8dk/5/ for which the code is as follow:

```
    var ChartData = '', ChartOptions = '';

function updategraph() {
    ChartData = [{
        value: 400,
        color: "#000",
        title: "#1"
    }, {
        value: 375,
        color: "#555",
        title: "#2"
    }, {
        value: 323,
        color: "#222",
        title: "#3"
    }, {
        value: 375,
        color: "#000",
        title: "#4"
    }, {
        value: 323,
        color: "#000",
        title: "#5"
    }];
    ChartOptions = {

    };

    new Chart(document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d")).PolarArea(ChartData, ChartOptions);
}
window.onload = function () {
    polarChart = new Chart(document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d")).PolarArea(ChartData, ChartOptions);
};

$("span").click(function () {
    updategraph();
});
```

If you click on "click here to draw" you will see the graph generated which is perfectly fine on Mozilla, Chrome, Safari (all latest desktop browsers).

Now when I try doing the same in mobile browser(iPhone 5 Safari, Samsung S4 Chrome) this behaves really strange. If you click on graph for second time, this graph will appear double of its first size and then again the same. It just gets expanded where it should behave like how it behaves in desktop browser.

First I thought this might be the issue only with PolarArea, but same issue appears with Pie too. You can check the same just changing PolarArea to Pie.

Any ideas on this ? May be some small mistake in my code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: on chrome 38, it goes the other way and gets smaller as you keep clicking

Comment: the issue seems to be with chartjs's helper function retinaScale, when commented out this issue does no happen http://jsfiddle.net/leighking2/1sc6L8dk/9/ looks like this might need to to be an issue raised on their github,

Comment: Thanks. Would if affect the functionality of chart if I remove this function from the library? and I have already raised this issue <https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js/issues/713> here

Comment: from what i could see no but you may want to test on a few different mobile devices/broswers, it worked fine on android chrome

Comment: oh did you mean remove the method or just comment out the call from the Chart constructor like I did in the example, if it's the comment out action then should be fine if you mean remove the function i am unsure who else trys to call it so would be careful and advice just commenting out the call to it in the constructor

Comment: Ok. Now, I will test this on other mobile browsers and will have it commented.

Comment: Thanks. I can confirm that removing 'helpers.retinaScale(this)' solves it for a Cordova app on Android 4.4.4